# VBA can't find ElementById when ran. Element exists when inspected but not when referenced by VBA

Tags: html, vba, web-scraping

I am trying to have VBA open a webpage, enter a password, and click submit. Techniques that have worked for me in the past do not seem to be working.

I Have tried using `.FindElementById` using both New InternetExplorerMedium and Selenium, while also trying Xpath with selenium. They are all failing at finding the Element on the page. While troubleshooting I noticed that if i try and rotate through a collection of Elements with the tag "input", the collection stays empty when using `.FindElementsByTag("input")`. This had me very confused, So then I had VBA open the web page and print the `outerHTML`. This printed:

HTML:

```
<FRAME id=top noResize marginHeight=10 src="top.html" frameBorder=0 name=top marginWidth=10 scrolling=no>
<FRAME id=Login noResize marginHeight=0 src="login.html" frameBorder=0 name=Login marginWidth=15 scrolling=no>
<FRAME id=bottom noResize marginHeight=10 src="bottom.html" frameBorder=0 name=bottom marginWidth=10 scrolling=no>
<NOFRAMES></NOFRAMES>
```

This is completely different than what i see when I manually inspect the password box i am trying to fill; I see:

```html
<input type="password" size="15" id="password" name="pswd" maxlength="33">
```

but this is not seen by the VBA when the page is loaded. What am i missing? This is my first question asked on StackOverflow so if my format is wonky i apologize.

Comment: Note that the `<frame>` and `<noframes>` elements have been obsolete for a number of years.

Comment: with selenium did you try switchTo .FindElementById("Login") to move into the login frame?

Comment: @QHarr , That worked! I used    switchTo .FindElementById("Login") , and once i switched into the frame, The FindElementById("password")  worked. Do I mark a post as solved?

Comment: I will post an answer you can accept

Comment: Awesome, I also attempted to mark your answer as useful but i am apparently to new.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you need to switch to the frame first then continue as before

```
.SwitchToFrame .FindElementById("Login")
```